# Execute last command in last active terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, vim, hotkeys

My current setup to develop is a terminal to execute my code and multiple vim sessions in which I write my code.

Since I constantly work on smaller functions and compile/execute them frequently I often have to switch to the terminal just to run my code and see the current output.

Is there a way I to set a hotkey to execute the last command (compile and execute) in the terminal while staying with the cursor in the vim window?

I run Ubuntu and use the i3 windows manager.

Comment: May be I misread your question, but if you hit "Up" arrow on the keyboard when you are in terminal window, it will restore in command line previously executed command. You can hit it multiple times to see  more commands from history

Comment: The problem is, that I have to switch to the terminal for this. I want to execute the terminal command while being in the vim window. I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use key mapping

```
:map <F9> @:
```

It will repeat last executed command.
Run your command with `:! ProgramYouWantToRun > /dev/pts/X`

Where right `X` is the terminal you want.
This `X` can be obtained by running `tty` command in the terminal where you want to execute your code.

When you press <kbd>F9</kbd> it will repeat execution `:! ProgramYouWantToRun > /dev/pts/X`

P.S.

More on key mapping in `vim` you can find [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))

Comment: This in combination with this kind of command: `:! ProgramYouWantToRun > /dev/pts/X` where X is the terminal you want. I find the right `X` by running `tty` in the terminal I want to execute my code.
Maybe you update your answer with this additional information.

Comment: @Jonas Added. Thanks for additional information!